# Convert a map to a JSON stringt

Tags: codenameone

I will like to convert a map to a valid JSONOBject or json string. I tried Result.fromContent(map).toString() which seems to work only if map is a valid Hashtable ( no null values). Is  there another way?

This is the NPE I get

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.processing.PrettyPrinter.toString(PrettyPrinter.java:178)
at com.codename1.processing.PrettyPrinter.print(PrettyPrinter.java:69)
at com.codename1.processing.PrettyPrinter.print(PrettyPrinter.java:60)
at com.codename1.processing.MapContent.toString(HashtableContent.java:113)
at com.codename1.processing.Result.toString(Result.java:314)
at userclasses.StateMachine.onEditorSave(StateMachine.java:284)
at generated.StateMachineBase.processCommand(StateMachineBase.java:257)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.processCommandImpl(UIBuilder.java:1634)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.access$100(UIBuilder.java:85)
at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder$FormListener.actionPerformed(UIBuilder.java:2757)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:345)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.actionCommandImplNoRecurseComponent(Form.java:1337)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:389)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:424)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:512)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2353)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2286)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:2459)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:1892)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:994)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:925)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
Result.fromContent(map).toString()
```

Works for Hashtable/HashMap semantics where null values aren't present so they are ignored. If you just want the null values to not appear you can just convert the Map to a HashMap which won't include null values.

If you are getting an exception I suggest posting the stack trace as part of the question and we might be able to fix that.

Comment: Missed that, I'll fix the answer. Thanks.

Comment: If I use Result.fromContent(map).toString(), I get an NPE. Looks like the Result use hash tables internally when pretty printing as the error here shows

Comment: I looked at the line of code related to the exception you are getting. It seems that your key is null so you did something like put(null, "Value") which I don't even know how to translate to valid JSON?
Was that intentional?

Comment: No it was not intentional but it could arise in the use case. I have updated the code to ensure the key is never null. It seems though that the value must also not be null which is a bit more difficult to achieve for the use case.

Comment: Whats the exception you get with a null value? (I mean the stack obviously)